# PXE boot from syslinux?

Tags: pxe, syslinux

I am trying to configure 2 boot options: one for PXE boot and one for local boot from the SSD. Is this achievable with syslinux? As far as I understand from the documentation and the source code, the variant "syslinux" supports local-boot only and the variant "pxelinux" supports PXE boot only. Is this correct? Or is there a way to support both, like with other bootloaders such as grub, u-boot, etc. where both are supported and the boot-command defines which one is used?

Comment: You could try to chainload pxelinux from syslinux.

Comment: You mean by putting pxelinux inside the /boot partition?

Comment: Yes. grub calls this "chainloading". I do not know how its called for syslinux, but I think it has the same feature somewhere, as syslinux menus often contain "Boot from HDD", what requires reading loading the bootloader from the hard disk and executing it.

Comment: @allo thanks for the suggestion. If this is the only way, you can post it as an answer. I just want to be sure that I understand correctly that PXE boot is not possible from the syslinux variant.

Comment: I do not want to post this as answer without having tested it to provide more details. It's just a direction what to test. You can write a self-answer how it works for you, when you got it working this way.

Answer (score 0):

see LOCALBOOT option on syslinux.cfg

https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Config#LOCALBOOT

Setting it to 0 in the default option shall work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).